# Why is the date not incrementing in the code below?

Tags: mysql, winforms

```
while(date.Year == year)
{
    query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Day VALUES(@Date,@DayOff)");
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DayOff",0);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    date.AddDays(1);
}
```

The table is empty before i run the code, it adds the first date 1 january 2014 then it tries to add the same date again although i am incrementing it.
I need to add the whole dates to the calendar,
 and the error i receive when i run this code is:
Violation of `PRIMARY KEY` constraint `'PK_Day'`. Cannot insert duplicate key in object `'dbo.Day'`.

The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`date.AddDays(1)` returns a new date, so your code should be:

```
while(date.Year == year)
{
  ....
  date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```